# How to write a bulgarian character using fwrite in PHP

Tags: php

I have a form, form inputs all other than English language.
 when click submit button i am getting the string using POST method. now i want to write strings in a new file called **'translate.php'**. if I use fwrite it works correctly for English but other language like **'bulgarian'** it will write a Unicode standard like `1&#1053;&#1040;&#1063;&#1040;&#1051;&#1054;` 
The actual word in en:**Home**
 in bulgarian:**НАЧАЛО.**
I can write in english but i cant write in bulgarian using fwrite.
Please anyone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

It's not `fwrite` that's transforming your characters, and those are HTML entities, not Unicode. I guess the encoding of your site is set to Latin-1. That means the browser will submit the data entered into a form to your server encoded in Latin-1. Bulgarian is not covered by Latin-1 and cannot be encoded in it, so the browser encodes those characters as HTML entities.

Two solutions:

1. use [`html_entity_decode($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')`](http://www.php.net/html_entity_decode) to decode those HTML entities to actual UTF-8
2. (preferred) serve your site in UTF-8 and/or set the `accept-charset="utf-8"` attribute on the form so the browser will submit UTF-8 data to the server

For an in-depth look into that, see [Handling Unicode in a Webapp](http://kunststube.net/frontback).

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is your case, but when you need the file with UTF8 content in another application, it has to contain a header marking it's a UTF8 file.

I used the code below to write to a file and give it to the browser as download. See the line below `add UTF-8 byte order mark`:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="UTF8 encoded file.sql"');
$f= fopen('php://output', 'w'); 
// add UTF-8 byte order mark
fwrite($f, pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf)); 
fwrite($f, $fileOutput); 
fclose($f);
```

Again, this is just something to have in mind if your current method of writing to the file doesn't work as expected (you didn't post the code for that).

Comment: A BOM is *not* "needed" for UTF-8. It's optional, and some software expects it, other supports it, yet other *fails* if a BOM is present. The safe choice is to *not* include the BOM, and only include it if the application you need to open the file with needs a BOM (mostly MS programs).

Comment: Yes, you are right. And this might not be the case here, as the file he writes to is a `translate.php` which probably will be just included in an other php script.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what your code looks like, but can you try :

```
....
$string = utf8_encode($posted_string);
$f = fopen('/path/to/translate.php',"w");
fwrite($f, $string);
fclose($f);
....
```

Comment: `utf8_encode` converts Latin-1 encoded strings to UTF-8. This is not useful at all unless you want to convert Latin-1 encoded text to UTF-8 encoded text.

Comment: Yes, thats the idea .. because i think the site encoding is set to Latin-1.

Comment: The important thing is the site ecoding, in that encoding the posted data will be retrieved .. If the site encoding is not correct there will be some problems I think.

Comment: The *only* thing `utf8_encode` does is encode Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1 to be exact) encoded strings to UTF-8! It says so right in the documentation.